# Trouble getting EnvironmentObject to update the UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I originally posted another question asking this in the context of a project I was trying to develop, but I can't even get it to work in a vacuum so I figured I'd start with the basics. As the title suggests, my EnvironmentObjects don't update the UI as they should; in the following code, the user enters text on the `ContentView` and should be able to see that text in the next screen `SecondView`.

EDITED:

```
import SwiftUI

class NameClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var myName = NameClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Type", text: $myName.name)
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Text("View2")
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(myName)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myself: NameClass
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(myself.name)")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(NameClass())
    }
}
```

However, the `SecondView` doesn't show the text that the user has written, but the default value of `name` (blank). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class NameClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var myName = NameClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Type", text: $myName.name)
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Text("View2")
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(myName)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myself: NameClass
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(myself.name)")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(NameClass())
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer—can you explain why you would use just SecondView() instead of SecondView().environmentObject(NameClass()))? In my main app, this breaks the preview if I don't include the .environmentObject.

Comment: You can even add your object to the environment this way too: SecondView().environmentObject(myName)

Comment: Sure, let me try that and I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Unfortunately, this sends out a syntax error. Can you demonstrate what you meant?

Comment: Have you updated the source with the answer I posted?

Comment: I used your code and changed the line for `NavigationLink(destination: SecondView())` to `NavigationLink(destination: SecondView().environmentObject(myName))`.

Comment: Change that environment object to state object, please compare it with yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234788/discussion-between-manny-m-and-rtxgamer).